# ckeditor initialise "find" plugin with ctrl+f

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am trying to initialise the `find` plugin from CKEditor, and I don't even know where to find their documentation for how to do this in the first place. I just need to init a plugin with a button press but rather a key press. So here's my code that I have so far...

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'ckeditor' );
editor.on("key",function(e){
    if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode ==  70) { // CTRL + F
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(editor);//init "find" here
    }
});
```

But even this doesn't override the default OS operation of `CTRL+F` so are there any suggestions on how to do this correctly? It should just open up the `find` plugin dialog when clicking `CTRL+F` inside the CKEditor editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well when all else fails and you can't find what you want here are two tips for any programmer. Looking at the Objects that your new instance of `ckeditor` returns for instance

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace("ckeditor");
console.log(editor);
```

or you can also view the main object which is `CKEDITOR`

```
console.log(CKEDITOR);
```

So here is what I found

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'ckeditor' );
CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady",function(){
    editor.document.$.body.addEventListener("keydown",function(e){
        if (e.keyCode === 114 || e.which === 114 || (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 70) || (e.ctrlKey && e.which === 70)) { 
            e.preventDefault();
            CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(43,editor);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

I tried doing `CKEDITOR.on("key",...` and it didn't seem to want to work with me so I just grabbed the body element.

Hope this helps for any others trying to get the `CTRL + F` function to work with the `find` plugin.

Comment: Hey @EasyBB, can you please help me to integrate the "find" plugin for CKEDITOR 4 as well, I am really trying to get this thing integrated but due to lack of documentation, I couldn't. Your help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you still having trouble with this?